# Vue mount multiple applications vs using Teleport in loop

Tags: vue.js, performance, vuejs3

I'm writing a browser extension to add a check mark on multiple elements on the current page.

I want to build this check mark (and its own tooltip) with *Vue*.

Assume I have a `document.querySelectorAll('selector for multiple')` to attach my *Vue* component to it, I see two options:

1. Loop through the element, and for each, create a new App:

   ```js
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    element.parentElement.insertBefore(div, element)

    createApp(App).mount(div)
   ```
2. Mount the `App` once, and inside the `App` use `Teleport` to mount a component to each element:

   ```js
   <Teleport v-for="element in elements" :to="element">
     <my-check-mark />
   </Teleport>
   ```

I think the second option is better, since I'm using only **one Vue engine**, but [*Vue* recommendation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/application.html#multiple-application-instances) is to create multiple instances:

> If you are using Vue to enhance server-rendered HTML and only need Vue to control specific parts of a large page, avoid mounting a single Vue application instance on the entire page. Instead, **create multiple small application instances** and mount them on the elements they are responsible for.

Why it is better?

Is it more efficient?